# Building Crypto++ 5.6.2 with Cygwin x86_64

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, cygwin, x86-64, crypto++

I am attempting to build CryptoPP with Cygwin x86_64, but I'm having some trouble with `osrng.cpp`.

I'm using gcc's C++ compiler, and I'm getting the following error at [line 50 of `osrng.cpp`](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/328/tree/trunk/c5/osrng.cpp#l50)

```
$ make
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -march=native -pipe -c osrng.cpp
osrng.cpp: In constructor ‘CryptoPP::MicrosoftCryptoProvider::MicrosoftCryptoProvider()’:
osrng.cpp:50:80: error: invalid conversion from ‘CryptoPP::MicrosoftCryptoProvider::ProviderHandle* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘HCRYPTPROV* {aka long long unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]
  if(!CryptAcquireContext(&m_hProvider, 0, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
                                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:95:0,
                 from osrng.cpp:19:
/usr/include/w32api/wincrypt.h:646:26: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘WINBOOL CryptAcquireContextA(HCRYPTPROV*, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, DWORD)’ [-fpermissive]
   WINIMPM WINBOOL WINAPI CryptAcquireContextA(HCRYPTPROV *phProv,LPCSTR szContainer,LPCSTR szProvider,DWORD dwProvType,DWORD dwFlags);
                          ^
GNUmakefile:208: recipe for target 'osrng.o' failed
make: *** [osrng.o] Error 1
```

I have successfully compiled the whole thing under the 32bit version of Cygwin before.

How can I fix this for the 64bit edition?

**EDIT** As suggested by [@Yakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580360/yaakov)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21506951/1296709), I replaced `if defined(_WIN64)if defined(__x86_64__)` by `if` in [line 30 of `osrng.h`](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/328/tree/trunk/c5/osrng.h#l30).
Sadly though, I immediately run into the next problem, indicated by the following error:

```
$ make
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -march=native -pipe -c fipstest.cpp
In file included from dll.h:30:0,
                 from fipstest.cpp:8:
osrng.h:34:19: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
  typedef unsigned __int64 ProviderHandle; // type HCRYPTPROV, avoid #include <windows.h>
                   ^
osrng.h:34:27: error: ‘ProviderHandle’ does not name a type
  typedef unsigned __int64 ProviderHandle; // type HCRYPTPROV, avoid #include <windows.h>
                           ^
osrng.h:38:2: error: ‘ProviderHandle’ does not name a type
  ProviderHandle GetProviderHandle() const {return m_hProvider;}
  ^
osrng.h:40:2: error: ‘ProviderHandle’ does not name a type
  ProviderHandle m_hProvider;
  ^
GNUmakefile:208: recipe for target 'fipstest.o' failed
make: *** [fipstest.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully, GCC error messages have improved significantly in recent releases.  The `{aka}`s tell you that there is a mismatch between `long` and `long long`.  Keep in mind that Win64 is LLP64: `long` is still only 32-bits, and you need a `long long` to match the size of a pointer.  Most (all?) other 64-bit platforms are LP64, meaning that `long` matches the size of a pointer.

In this particular case, see the `if defined(_WIN64)` in [`osrng.h`](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/328/tree/trunk/c5/osrng.h#l30); you will need to change that condition to `if defined(__x86_64__)` instead.

You might run into problems with the `__int64` type as well. Replace those with `long long`. (Occurs [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/328/tree/trunk/c5/config.h#l113), [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/328/tree/trunk/c5/config.h#l220) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/328/tree/trunk/c5/osrng.h#l31).)

Comment: I tried that, but now I run into the next error. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Replace the `_int64`s with `long long`.  You may also need to make similar changes elsewhere in the code; `grep -r _WIN64` should help you find other possible cases.

Comment: That did the trick. I issued an edit to include this last comment of yours in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find `word64` useful. From Crypto++'s `config.h`:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
    typedef unsigned __int64 word64;
    #define W64LIT(x) x##ui64
#else
    typedef unsigned long long word64;
    #define W64LIT(x) x##ULL
#endif
```

There's a couple of Cygwin defines in there too. But they don't look interesting. For example:

```
#ifndef TYPE_OF_SOCKLEN_T
#   if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#       define TYPE_OF_SOCKLEN_T int
#   else
#       define TYPE_OF_SOCKLEN_T ::socklen_t
#   endif
#endif

#if defined(__CYGWIN__) && defined(PREFER_WINDOWS_STYLE_SOCKETS)
#   define __USE_W32_SOCKETS
#endif
```

(Sorry about the comment here. Its too bing to fit in the little comment block).